# Which macro actually typesets images in graphicx?

Tags: macros, graphics

I was looking through `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/source/latex/graphics/graphicx.dtx` and trying to figure out what macro actually typesets the image file.

For example, on the user level, we type

```
\usepackage{graphicx} % Load the graphicx.dtx file within preamble
\includegraphics{file} % Load the image file within body
```

But `\includegraphics` does a few things. I think it

- separates file name from file extension
- iterates all acceptable file extensions so that you don't have to enter it explicitly
- creates error on bad input
- etc.?

In the macro definition of `\Ginclude@graphics`, I found `\Gin@setfile`. Does this type**set** the file?  What mechanism determines draft mode vs non-draft mode?

The reason being is I would like to redefine or patch it to include the file name centered below the image.

## `\Gin@setfile` as of May 4, 2015

From `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty`

```
\def\Gin@setfile#1#2#3{%
  \ifx\\#2\\\Gread@false\fi
  \ifGin@bbox\else
    \ifGread@
      \csname Gread@%
         \expandafter\ifx\csname Gread@#1\endcsname\relax
           eps%
         \else
           #1%
         \fi
      \endcsname{\Gin@base#2}%
    \else
      \Gin@nosize{#3}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \Gin@viewport@code
  \Gin@nat@height\Gin@ury bp%
  \advance\Gin@nat@height-\Gin@lly bp%
  \Gin@nat@width\Gin@urx bp%
  \advance\Gin@nat@width-\Gin@llx bp%
  \Gin@req@sizes
  \expandafter\ifx\csname Ginclude@#1\endcsname\relax
    \Gin@drafttrue
    \expandafter\ifx\csname Gread@#1\endcsname\relax
      \@latex@error{Can not include graphics of type: #1}\@ehc
      \global\expandafter\let\csname Gread@#1\endcsname\@empty
    \fi
  \fi
  \leavevmode
  \ifGin@draft
      \hb@xt@\Gin@req@width{%
        \vrule\hss
        \vbox to \Gin@req@height{%
           \hrule \@width \Gin@req@width
           \vss
           \edef\@tempa{#3}%
           \rlap{ \ttfamily\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@tempa}%
           \vss
           \hrule}%
        \hss\vrule}%
  \else
    \@addtofilelist{#3}%
    \ProvidesFile{#3}[Graphic file (type #1)]%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\csname Ginclude@#1\endcsname{#3}}%
    \dp\z@\z@
    \ht\z@\Gin@req@height
    \wd\z@\Gin@req@width
  \box\z@
  \fi}
```

Comment: The actual file inclusion is handed to the driver, with different code for the various engines

Comment: the test for draft mode is `\ifGin@draft` with it just printing the filepath if true `\else` calling the back end defined code to include a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main part of the code you quote is

```
\setbox\z@\hbox{\csname Ginclude@#1\endcsname{#3}}%
```

which calls `\Ginclude@xxx` where `xxx` is the file type (determined from the extension or passed as an key to `\includegraphics`) so if `xxx` is `eps` this will call `\Ginclude@eps` and if the driver specified (in an option or set in `graphics.cfg`) is `dvips` then `dvips.def` will have been loaded which defines EPS inclusion by

```
\def\Ginclude@eps#1{%
 \message{<#1>}%
  \bgroup
  \def\@tempa{!}%
  \dimen@\Gin@req@width
  \dimen@ii.1bp%
  \divide\dimen@\dimen@ii
  \@tempdima\Gin@req@height
  \divide\@tempdima\dimen@ii
    \special{PSfile="#1"\space
      llx=\Gin@llx\space
      lly=\Gin@lly\space
      urx=\Gin@urx\space
      ury=\Gin@ury\space
      \ifx\Gin@scalex\@tempa\else rwi=\number\dimen@\space\fi
      \ifx\Gin@scaley\@tempa\else rhi=\number\@tempdima\space\fi
      \ifGin@clip clip\fi}%
  \egroup}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation with a patched and redefined `\includegraphics`.  Currently, the width of the filename is not accounted for, but one can do that by changing the `T` argument to `F` in the `\stackengine` argument list.  The underset gap of the filename is currently 3pt.  Note that the filename is generated properly, regardless of whether the extension was specified in calling argument.

EDITED to handle special characters in filename, such as underscores.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% TO PROPERLY FORMAT UNDERSCORES IN FILENAMES
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,xpatch}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\Gin@setfile}{\xdef\file@root{#3}}{}{}
\let\svincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \savestack\tmp{\svincludegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \stackengine{3pt}{\tmp}{\detokenize\expandafter{\file@root}}%
    {U}{c}{F}{T}{S}% <- CHANGE T TO F TO ACCOUNT FOR FILENAME WIDTH
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Does it work?  \includegraphics[width=.7in]{example-image-a}

Here is another test \includegraphics[width=2.7in]{example-image-c.jpg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This addresses the actual concern of the OP. Therefore +1.

Comment: @AlexG Both answers are helpful! David Carlisle answered my  question-in his usual minimalist fashion. Steven was nice enough to go above and beyond the question and provide a solution to one of my goals (maybe because it was fun to do? :D). Some people on this site are explanation-oriented, while some are goal-oriented. I'd like to recognize that this community has a good mix of both types of experts. So give them both +1 :)

Comment: @macmadness86  Thanks!  The optimist sees the glass half full; the pessimist sees the glass half empty; the engineer sees the glass twice as big as necessary (or perhaps the engineer only sees the glass with a factor of safety of 2.0)

Comment: @macmadness86. I did, by the way, even before Stevens answer appeared.